# Merge two tensor in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

Tensor a:

```
tensor([[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]])
```

Tensor b:

```
tensor([4,4,4,4])
```

Question 1:

How to merge two tensors and get result c:

```
tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Question 2: How to divide tensor c and get original a and b.

Answer (score 4):

Question 1: Merge two tensors -

```py
torch.cat((a, b.unsqueeze(1)), 1)
>>> tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4],
            [1, 2, 3, 4],
            [1, 2, 3, 4],
            [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

First, we use [torch.unsqueeze](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze) to add single dim in `b` tensor to match `a` dim to be concanate. Then use [torch.cat](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.cat) Concatenates tensors `a` and `b`.

Question 2:

```py
a = c[:][:,:-1]
a
>>> tensor([[1, 2, 3],
            [1, 2, 3],
            [1, 2, 3],
            [1, 2, 3]])

b = c[:][:,-1:].squeeze(1)
b
>>> tensor([4, 4, 4, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to slightly modify tensor b:

```
a = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3],
                  [1, 2, 3],
                  [1, 2, 3],
                  [1, 2, 3]])

b = torch.tensor([4,4,4,4])
b = b.reshape(1, 4)
```

Then you get your "joined" tensor:

```
c = torch.cat((a, torch.t(b)), 1)
```

And backward:

```
a1 = c[:,:-1]
b1 = torch.t(c[:,-1:])
```

Comment: In the question given dim of tensor `b` is `torch.Size([4])` and here you are taking `torch.Size([1, 4])` please edit answer.